# How can I observe the current route name from the application controller in Ember 2.7.1?

Tags: ember.js

I've been doing this previously as follows:

```
pageDidChange: Ember.observer('currentPath', function() {
    this.set('pageClassName', this.get('currentPath').replace(/[.]/g, '-'));    
}),
```

However this no longer works as the currentPath property seems to have disappeared. I also can't find any mention of it in the API docs on the EmberJS website.

Should I now be doing this differently?

Comment: Hi, I just tried on Ember 2.7.0 and `currentPath` is still available. Alternatively you have `currentRouteName`.

Comment: Another suggestion is to turn `pageClassName` into a computed property, if possible. `pageClassName: Ember.computed('currentPath', function() { return this.get('currentPath').replace(/[.]/g, '-')); })`

Comment: If you are using ember 2.7 or above, find my solution below. Verify if you find it helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to access the current route,

1) direct one in hbs

```
{{currentRouteName}}
```

2) in your controller

```
this.get('router.currentPath');
```

3) accessing the router information, from your route

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
  this._super(controller, model);
  let targetRoute = this._router._routerMicrolib.activeTransition.targetName;
  controller.set('currentPath', targetRoute);
},
```

in your template:

```
{{currentPath}}
```